# Required Argument Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy haciendo un bot en .py y decidi poner un say pero en embed, este es es el codigo:

```
@client.command()
async def say(self, ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_author(name="Anuncio!", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Sent by {ctx.message.author}", value=str(message))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

El bot anda y todo, pero al poner !say (Lo que sea) me manda lo siguiente

```
PS D:\GN> & C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe d:/GN/bot.py
¡Estoy listo!
Ignoring exception in command say:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 847, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 784, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 699, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 535, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: message is a required argument that is missing.
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Por alguna razón la función `say` no está recibiendo el parámetro "message" que es obligatorio. Prueba una cosa: escribe `if message:` justo antes del primer `await` e indenta el resto del código. Después del segundo `await` baja una indentación y pon: `else: print("No hay mensaje")` a ver que pasa. Básicamente encapsula el código de la función dentro del condicional if-else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue quitar el self, ya que no estaba en un cog